# Operations on ideals of polynomial rings

Tags: packages, polynomials, algebra, groebner-bases

There is [`GroebnerBasis`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroebnerBasis.html.en) to compute a Gröbner basis of an ideal in a polynomial ring, but I am looking for a package to perform operations on ideals $I,J\subseteq\Bbb Q[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, such as computing the following:

- $I\cap J$
- $I+J$
- $(I:J)$
- $\sqrt{I}$
- $\dim(I)$

It would also be desirable to have a method for computing the primary decomposition. I can implement all of that myself, but I'd rather use an existing package if one exists.